# GWT: Loading an Applet inside an application

Tags: java, gwt, applet, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to integrate an existing applet packaged as jar file in an existing GWT application built with maven.

Now I am not being able to figure out, why the applet class is not being found. A `ClassNotFoundException` is being thrown when I try to load the applet, saying that the applet class cannot be found.

The GWT Maven project has several modules and the applet I want to integrate is in its own Maven module.
The applet jar file is being signed and packaged as in the final war file for the GWT app by the maven build process.

When I deploy the war file in a Tomcat server I have the following structure under the webapps folder:

```
webapps
  my_gwt_app
      WEB-INF
        classes
        deploy
        lib
          signed_applet.jar
          other_application_dependency.jar
        views
        web.xml
```

Here is the HTML result which is being generated by my GWT presenter:

```html
<applet code="com.example.MyApplet.class" archive="/my_gwt_app/WEB-INF/lib/signed_applet.jar" width="1000" height="800" id="my-applet">
    <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
</applet>
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `<param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">` Whatever you are trying to achieve there, it will not add permissions to the applet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the jar file path configuration.
I put it in the my_gwt_app/gwt_module/applet directory and configured the applet with this jar path.
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the `lib` or `classes` directory is available to be served to clients that visit the site.  It will be necessary to move the Jar to another place on the server.

In addition to that:

The following path is simply wrong.

```
archive="/my_gwt_app/WEB-INF/lib/signed_applet.jar"
```

`WEB-INF` would typically be the 'root' of the site.

---

```html
<param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
```

Whatever you are trying to achieve there, it will not add permissions to the applet.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for the hint!
What would be the right path configuration in your opinion, considering that I am using maven to package the application?
archive="/signed_applet.jar"

Comment: I don't use Maven, but if you can organize it to put the archive at `WEB-INF/signed_applet.jar` then `archive="/signed_applet.jar"` should work just fine to load it.

Comment: I've made those changes.
Unfortunatelly, the signed jar still not being found and I still getting the ClassNotFoundException.
Is there perhaps anything else that could be avoiding the jar to be found?

Comment: Surf to (your real/test **server** address)/signed_applet.jar and check if it offers the Jar for download.  Report back with the URL you tried, and the result.

Answer (score 0):

I added the "applet" folder under the root folder (http://dev-server.com:8080/my_gwt_app/ not under WEB-INF) and called the URL "http://dev-server.com:8080/my_gwt_app/applet/signed_applet.jar" in the browser. The jar could be found.

But when I configure my applet like

```
<applet id="my-applet" width="1000" height="800" 
     code="com.example.MyApplet.class"" archive="../applet/signed_applet.jar">
</applet>
```

I still getting the ClassNotFoundException.